# map[string] struct inside struct

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "jailbreaks": [
    {
      "jailbroken": false,
      "name": "",
      "version": "",
      "url": "",
      "anleitung": [],
      "ios": {
        "start": "10.2.1"
      },
      "caveats": "",
      "platforms": []
    },
    {
      "jailbroken": true,
      "name": "Yalu102",
      "version": "beta 6",
      "url": "https://domain-dl.tld",
      "anleitung": [
        { "blog": "title", "link": "http://domain.tld/" },
        { "blog": "Test", "link": "http://google.at" }
      ],
      "ios": {
        "start": "10.2"
      },
      "caveats": "some text here",
      "platforms": [
        "Windows",
        "OS X",
        "Linux"
      ]
    },
```

And I create the object to work with like this:

```
type Jailbreak struct {
    Jailbroken bool   `json:"jailbroken"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Version    string `json:"version"`
    URL        string `json:"url"`
    Anleitung  map[string]struct {
        Name string `json:"blog"`
        Link string `json:"link"`
    } `json:"anleitung"`

    Firmwares struct {
        Start string `json:"start"`
        End   string `json:"end"`
    } `json:"ios"`

    Platforms []string `json:"platforms"`
    Caveats   string   `json:"caveats"`
}
```

When I want to build my go program I get an error, that the JSON file cannot be read. But as soon as I delete the `map[string]struct` I can compile and run the program without any error and everything works fine. 
Am I messing around with something or is there an error in my JSON file?

Comment: In the json `"anleitung"` is an array, you can't unmarshal that into a map.

Comment: anleitung property in JSON is an array not an object. It is not compatible to unmarshal.

Answer (score 1):

The json provided is not valid (as the array does not have a closing `]` and the top level json object lacks another closing `}`) so let's assume it's like:

```
{
  "jailbreaks": [
    {
      "jailbroken": false,
      "name": "",
      "version": "",
      "url": "",
      "anleitung": [],
      "ios": {
        "start": "10.2.1",
        "end": ""
      },
      "platforms": [],
      "caveats": ""
    },
    {
      "jailbroken": true,
      "name": "Yalu102",
      "version": "beta 6",
      "url": "https://domain-dl.tld",
      "anleitung": [
        {
          "blog": "title",
          "link": "http://domain.tld/"
        },
        {
          "blog": "Test",
          "link": "http://google.at"
        }
      ],
      "ios": {
        "start": "10.2",
        "end": ""
      },
      "platforms": [
        "Windows",
        "OS X",
        "Linux"
      ],
      "caveats": "some text here"
    }
  ]
}
```

The data structure `Jailbreaks` (first one), marshals-to/unmarshals-from this json properly:

```
type Jailbreaks struct {
    List []Jailbreak `json:"jailbreaks"`
}

type Jailbreak struct {
    Jailbroken bool   `json:"jailbroken"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Version    string `json:"version"`
    URL        string `json:"url"`
    Anleitung  []struct {
        Name string `json:"blog"`
        Link string `json:"link"`
    } `json:"anleitung"`

    Firmwares struct {
        Start string `json:"start"`
        End   string `json:"end"`
    } `json:"ios"`

    Platforms []string `json:"platforms"`
    Caveats   string   `json:"caveats"`
}
```

As you see `Anleitung` is declared as a slice (not a map).

Answer (score -1):

Use `omitempty` flag for when your "anleitung" is empty in JSON to be consumed. Beware though, when that is the case, your `Jailbreak` struct won't have an "anleitung" field.

Change your map's json flag to to;

```
Anleitung   map[string]struct {
    Name string `json:"blog"`
    Link string `json:"link"`
} `json:"anleitung,omitempty"`
```

Option 2;

I guess you could also use `Anleitung   map[string]interface{}` but that is better for "holding a map of strings to arbitrary data types". In your case the data is not arbitrary but rather, empty I guess. And looks like that is just temporary.

I'd go for option 1, then I'd check if my struct contains any `Anleitung` data or not before accessing it.